# How do I determine which TabPage is currently active?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, tabcontrol, tabpage

I want to learn which tabpage in my window is active. My aim is something like this:

```
  if Tabpage1 is active then
   .....
  end if

  if Tabpage2 is active then
  ...
  end if
```

I will write it on form closing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to query the *container* control (the [`TabControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx) control) for this information, not the individual `TabPage` controls that it hosts.

And you have two options for doing so, depending on the type of information that you wish to receive. You can either use the **[`SelectedIndex` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindex.aspx)**, which returns the zero-based index of the currently selected tab page, or you can use the **[`SelectedTab` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab.aspx)**, which returns an instance of the `TabPage` class representing the currently selected tab page.

Code sample:

```vb
If myTabControl.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
    ' Do something for the first tab page
ElseIf myTabControl.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
    ' Do something for the second tab page
Else
    ' Uh-oh! One of the other tab pages that you didn't
    ' mention in your question is selected!
End If
```

Or:

```vb
If myTabControl.SelectedTab = myFirstTabPage Then
    ' Do something for the first tab page
ElseIf myTabControl.SelectedTab = mySecondTabPage Then
    ' Do something for the second tab page
Else
    ' Uh-oh! One of the other tab pages that you didn't
    ' mention in your question is selected!
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a better way, especially if you adjust your tabpages order either programatically or in the view itself.

```
if (tabControl.SelectedTab.Name == "tabName" )
{
     .. do stuff
}
```